# How can i do relationship between posts with tags and posts with categories in same table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5

I have 4 tables in my database which are: `posts`, `categories`, `tags` and `relation_with_tag_category`

In my Post model I have a 'belongsToMany' relationship:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_relation')->withTimestamps();
}

public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'category_relation')->withTimestamps();
}
```

How can I do relationship with post and tag and category by the same table which I explain above and how can I display in my blade view?

It's just like wordpress term relationship

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relations works correctly (I cant tell if i only see one model relation) you can query your tables using [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) function.

`$myPosts = Post::with(['categories','tags'])->get();`

And use them like this

`$myPosts->categories->all();`

`$myPosts->tags->all();`

Comment: It's ok but when i inserting post with sync tags and categories that are not inserting in database

Comment: @AnwarulIslam Update your question and post that instead adding it to a comment